# Python, the web page seems not to see ALL my DATA and does not provide the correct answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I enter this URL I will get some XML formatted text as a response:

http://skrutten.nada.kth.se/scrut/svesve/?text=g%E5&url=&xmlout=on&x=Granska

Now I try to write a Python function that POST a message to the web page and I should  get the same information. However, I am getting less information from the web page. It seems that some data are not "seen"(text) but I do not get any error messages. For instance, I am not sure if I am handling the coding in a correct way (I tried with utf-8 with no difference)

Any suggestions about my misstake?

```
def fetch_web (name, par1):
    """Fetch the web data defined by name and return a string with the web page"""

    if name == "granska":
        url = "http://skrutten.nada.kth.se/scrut/svesve/"
        values = {"text":par1,"xmlout":"on","x":"Granska","url":""}
        code = "ISO-8859-1"
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode(code)

    req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    page = response.read()
    return page.decode("ISO-8859-1")

print (fetch_web("granska","gå"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def fetch_web (name, par1):
    """Fetch the web data defined by name and return a string with the web page"""

    if name == "granska":
        url = "http://skrutten.nada.kth.se/scrut/svesve/"
        values = {"text":par1,"xmlout":"on","x":"Granska","url":""}
        code = "ISO-8859-1"

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode(code)
    full_url = "%s?%s" % (url, data)

    req = urllib.request.Request(full_url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    page = response.read()
    return page.decode("ISO-8859-1")

print (fetch_web("granska","gå"))
```

There may be issues caused by the lack of a file name at the end of a URL.  I've experienced this same thing in the past with several of my scrips where it doesn't add a "?" between the URL and post data when there is only a trailing "/" at the end of the URL.  I think it's a bug with the `urllib2.Request` class, but since I found a workaround I have been putting off looking into if a bug report exists or not.

Also, if `name != "granska"` you are going to get an exception as `url` and `values` will be undefined variables when used in the `data = ...` lines.

Comment: Happy to help :).  If you can accept the answer it would help other people who have this problem in the future know that this solution works

Comment: Could you say a couple of words about the purpose of full_url. It seems that you are concatenating the url and (?) data. Shouldn't the statement urllib.request.Request(url,data) be doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it _should_, but I've experienced this same thing in the past with several of my scrips where it doesn't add a "?" between the URL and post data when there is only a trailing "/" at the end of the URL.  I think it's a bug, but since I found the workaround I have been putting off looking into if a bug report exists or not.

Comment: Ok! I got this problem with this specific web page but I have succeeded with other web page that was also terminated by /

Comment: It may have to do with how the web server handles the request that urllib2 sends as well.  I'm not sure if urllib2 actually sends the post data in the header, or if it adds it to the url string.  It might be handled in different ways by different servers which would explain the inconsistent behavior.