# Python 3, how to convert a string into "iso-8859-1" to use in html

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I type the text "gå" in a swedish web page, the html generates the following field: g%E5. That is, the letter a-ring (å) is coded as %E5. I assume that they are using ISO-8859-1.

If I generate the same html address using a Python 3.0 script the string "gå" is coded as g%C3%A5. Now the letter a-ring(å) is coded as %C3%A5. I assume that Python 3.0 (string)is using utf-8 to code the a-ring in this way.

How can I use Python 3 to generate the html address with g%E5?

Comment: Look more carefully at [chown's answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638375/python-the-web-page-seems-not-to-see-all-my-data-and-does-not-provide-the-correc/7638682#7638682). It shows how to encode and decode unicode into `iso-8559-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this Python source file:

```
#coding: utf-8
print repr(u"gå".encode("ISO-8859-1"))
```

and got

```
'g\xe5'
```

as output.

I'm using Python 2, but it should be the same for Python 3 without the `u` before the unicode literal, possibly without the coding line, and with `ascii` instead of `repr`.

So it should be as simple as specifying `"ISO-8859-1"` as the encoding.

Without seeing your exact code I can't tell you where specifically to do that. Check out the docs for whatever you're using for how to set the encoding.